# How to pass an Uri content from one class to other

Tags: android, firebase

I have my `MainActivity.class` and I want to pass my Uri content to another class.

my Uri is this one:

```
public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
  // Get a URL to the uploaded content
  @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") 
  Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
}
```

and I want to get this Uri in my `MainActivity2.class`, so I can get the URL string and paste it to the database reference to upload to firebase, so my user has the Url of my file uploaded, the thing is that I don't know how to pass this string

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
  mDatabase.child(personID).child("URL").setValue(downloadURL);        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the **MainActivity.java**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
intent.putExtra("downloadUrl", downloadUrl);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the **MainActivity2.java**:

```
Uri downloadUrl = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("downloadUrl");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start the activity with intent and Uri, something like this:

```
Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);

// put uri to intent
intent.setData(downloadUrl);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then you can get the Uri from the intent in your MainActivity2 with:

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  ...

  // Get the Uri from the intent
  Uri downloadUrl = getIntent().getData();

  // Then do something with the Uri.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First in your `MainActivity.class` do this:

```
Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("downloadUri", String.valueOf(downloadUri));
in.putExtras(b);
startActivity(in);
```

And in you `NextActivity.class` do this:

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(extras.getString(downloadUri));
```

Here in `NextActivity.class` you have the `downloadUri`.